# Setting frame of view with Javascript in NativeScript

Tags: javascript, ios, nativescript

I'm struggling to figure out how to position a view in the page on iOS.

Is it possible to set the `frame` of a view using Javascript?

I've tried the following but it doesn't seem to work. I see the label added to the page but my frame is ignored.

XML

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="onLoaded" navigatedTo="onNavigatedTo" class="page">
    <StackLayout id="test">

    </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

JS

```
var labelModule = require("ui/label");

var page;

exports.onLoaded = function(args) {
    page = args.object;
}

exports.onNavigatedTo = function(args) {
    var test = page.getViewById('test');

    positionEl(test);    
}

function positionEl(el) {
    var myLabel = new labelModule.Label();
    myLabel.text = 'My label';
    myLabel.ios.frame = {origin: {x:200, y:200}, size: {width: 200, height:200}};

    el.addChild(myLabel);
}
```

CSS

```
#test {
    background-color: red;
}

#test Label {
    background-color: green;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

This results in the image on the left. I would expect (or would like) it to look like the image on the right.

For [reasons](https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/absolute-fixed-positioning-without-absolutelayout/648) I don't want to use an AbsoluteLayout for this. I need a solution that allows arbitrary positioning within *any* parent element type.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `StackLayout` is probably not best suited for arbitrary positioning. You could use an `AbsoluteLayout`:

```
  <AbsoluteLayout id="test" backgroundColor="green">
  </AbsoluteLayout>
```

.. and do it like this:

```
function positionEl(el) {
  var myLabel = new labelModule.Label();
  myLabel.text = 'My label';
  myLabel.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  myLabel.textAlignment = "center";
  myLabel.width = 200;
  myLabel.height = 200;

  el.addChild(myLabel);
  AbsoluteLayout.setTop(myLabel, 200);
  AbsoluteLayout.setLeft(myLabel, 100);
}
```

Comment: Hi Eddy. There are reasons that I don't wish to use AbsoluteLayout (https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/absolute-fixed-positioning-without-absolutelayout/648). I'm hoping to find a solution that allows arbitrary positioning in _any_ element.

Answer (score 0):

You may try with style:

```
Object.assign(myLabel.style, 
      {
         left: '200px', 
         top: '200px', 
         width: '200px', 
         height: '200px'
      }
);
```